# Jekyll/liquid list parameter?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I wanted to create a simply include which simplifies creating a carousel. So I was looking for the syntax to give a list of image urls as a parameter. However I couldn't find anything about this.

```
{% include carousel.html images=WHAT HERE? %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list as a string then convert it into an array inside your snippet. This is the way I would do it.

```
{% assign urls = 'url1.jpg,url2.jpg,url3.jpg' %}

{% include carousel.html images=urls %}
```

Of course this is the same as:

```
{% include carousel.html images='url1.jpg,url2.jpg,url3.jpg' %}
```

#### carousel.html

```
{% assign images = include.images | split: ',' %}
{% for image in images %}
   {{ image }}
{% endfor %}
```